# How to print a specific re.Match object

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to print out a certain re.match object from the results?

**Python**

```
sentence = ''' 
Tue, 20 August 2019
17:30 - 21:00 CEST 
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'\d\d[:]\d\d')
matches = pattern.finditer(sentence)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
    print(match.group(0))
```

**Output** --> `print(match)`

```
<re.Match object; span=(20, 25), match='17:30'>
<re.Match object; span=(28, 33), match='21:00'>
```

**Output** --> `print(match.group(0))`

```
17:30
21:00
```

Is it possible to only `print` a certain match?

```
print(first re.Match object in list) = 17:30

print(second re.Match object in list) = 21:00
```

**Attempts** --> my attempts to solve this

```
for match in matches:
    print(matches[0].group(0))
    print(match.group(0))
    print(match[0])
    print(match)
    print(match.__getitem__(0))
    print(match.group(0))
    print(match.groupdict(0))
    print(match.start(0))
    print(match.groups)
    print(match.group(1))
    print(re.match(r'<img.*?>', matches))
    print(re.match(r'<img.*?>', match).group(0))
```

Comment: That is what you are doing, you get all matches, one by one, and  get the values using `print(match.group(0))`. You may add a counter if you wish, increment it in the `for` cycle and check if it is the number of match you need to print.

Comment: What do you mean by `a certain match`? Do you want to capture both times at once and print each?

Comment: Sorry it it was unclear. I am trying to capture a certain match from the list that is produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add a counter if you wish, increment it in the for cycle and check if it is the number of match you need to print.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Eq2U7N) online:

```
import re

sentence = ''' 
Tue, 20 August 2019
17:30 - 21:00 CEST 
'''
pattern = re.compile(r'\d\d:\d\d')
cnt = 0          # Initialize the counter
wanted = [1,2]   # Defines the 1-based IDs of the matches you want to display

for match in pattern.finditer(sentence):
    cnt += 1                  # Increment the counter
    if cnt in wanted:         # If the ID is in wanted IDs
        print(match.group())  # Print it
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However how can i divide the output and therefore isolate the it into two different print statements? this returns both Object groups. I tried playing around with your code but i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Redstain Sorry, I do not understand, what output do you need for which string?

Comment: I edited the end of my question to make it more understandable. Maybe i am going at this problem incorrectly. How can i for example only print the second match of the list i produce ---> print(second re.Match object in list) = 21:00 or print the first match ---> print(first re.Match object in list) = 17:30

Comment: @Redstain Just use my code and `wanted = [1]` to get the first match or `wanted = [2]` to get the second

Comment: Ah sorry! i was incorrectly attempting your code. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

`for match in matches` == you do the printing for all your matches.

Do this:

```
sentence = ''' 
Tue, 20 August 2019
17:30 - 21:00 CEST 
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'\d\d[:]\d\d')
matches = pattern.findall(sentence) # returns a list
print(matches[0].group(0)) # get first element from the list (0-indexed) and get its first group
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I thought this was the right answer. However when i simply copy and paste this code i get the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: I could be wrong but I think re.findall() doesn't return a match object (or a list of them), it always returns a list of strings (or a list of tuples of strings, in the case of there being more than one capturing group). And a list doesn't have a .group() method.

Comment: This code can't work because it will always throw an exception once there is no match or if the specified index does not exist.

Comment: @Redstain you're right, I just modified your code without remembering this. But the idea is the same - if you want to print one, don't for-loop through all. :P

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not something a ternary operator can't fix. `print(matches[0] if matches else "No match was found")` (already with fix that findall returns list of strings, not list of matches)

Comment: @h4z3 Sure, however, the `finditer` is still a better idea IMHO, because once you get the segment you need you may break out of the loop and with `findall`, you will have to first collect *all* matches before accessing an item at a specific index. So, this involves a bit more overhead.